# Semisimplicity of the p-adic étale Tate module over $F_p(t)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be a finitely generated field of positive characteristic p.
Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$ and write $T_p(A)$ for the $p$-adic étale Tate module of $A$. Is it known if the natural action of $Gal(k^{sep}|k)$ over $T_p(A)$ is semisimple?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275355/galois-action-on-p-adic-tate-module-of-abelian-variety-over-finite-field-semis?rq=1

Comment: @TKe thank you for your answer. In that answer, k is a finite field, while here k is a finitely generated field. For the moment i'm not able to deduce the case when k is finitely generated from the situation when k is finite.

Comment: I tried to see if one could do something following either (1) Deligne's proof of semisimplicity of geometric monodromy for ell-adic etale cohomology or (2) the Arakelov-Faltings proof of the Tate conjecture for endomorphisms of abelian varieties over global fields. I don't think (1) works because the p-adic analogue would be in the setting of crystalline cohomology or something but the relationship between crystalline monodromy and monodromy of the p-adic Tate module is not obvious. But (2) might work.

Comment: Given a subspace of the p-adic Tate module which, consider the quotient of the abelian variety by the $p^n$-torsion image of that subspace for all $n$. If these are isomorphic for infinitely many $n$ then I think you can check that the subspace is complemented. Then maybe you can bound the height and prove finiteness and deduce that infinitely many are isomorphic.